# I want to use many parallel LEDs. Can this IC (BP3309) help me to control them?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, parallel

I want to use many parallel LEDs. Can the BP3309 IC 
[(datasheet in Chinese)](https://www.nikom.biz/pdf/BP3309_BPSemi.pdf)
help me to control the LEDs? I want consistent brightness.

Comment: Your url is broken, the question is useless because of that, [edit] it to fix it

Comment: Link fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The chip you inexpertly linked is a BP3309: -

[image]

Clearly the LEDs shown in the circuit are in series (not parallel) so this is what I'd recommend. If you want to put LEDs in parallel this chip will not work effectively because you cannot control the current through individual LEDs.

Also, wiring LEDs in parallel requires a series current limiting element per LED and this soon mounts up to an inefficient method. Stick to wiring them in series is my advice.

On another matter, you should try to find a datasheet (pdf document) that is written in English if you want more help understanding this chip.